# FXML fails to load on subsequent runs on OS X

Tags: java, macos, javafx

I'm on Java 8u91. My application UI is a mix of Swing and some JavaFX. What's gotten me stumped is my application runs fine for the 1st time after installation, but fails to load on subsequent tries. This only happens on OS X.

I get a **javafx.fxml.loadException** opening up the FXML which is caused by an NPE occuring at **javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadTypeForPackage**

My code is really simple:

```
    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = null;

    try {
        fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource(
                "DialogFX.fxml"));
    } catch(Exception e) {
    }

    fxmlLoader.setRoot(this);
    fxmlLoader.setController(this);

    try {
        fxmlLoader.load();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

I've also tried using the complete and relative path to the resource. They all fail on OS X, whereas everything (all path types included) work on Windows and Linux.

A small clue I found as to why it runs alright the 1st time, is that during the 1st launch, there are a couple of items that get done on the main application thread (e.g. copying small resources from the application jar into certain directories), while the JavaFX thread does it's own thing.

But the JFX components are not dependent on these installed resources; I hazard some sort of delay helps get over a JFX bug on OS X, and since the installation process doesn't occur on following runs, the JFX bug just happens.

I know I'm lacking more specifics. I'm hard pressed myself finding any substance that will help me fix this. I was hoping someone might have an idea as to what's going on.

Comment: I'm using `loader.setLocation(ClassName.class.getResource("FXMLFILE.fxml"))`

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that.

Comment: Nope, didn't work. I also tried using the blank constructor for FXMLLoader, and using FXMLLoader.setLocation(), after, but the same error occurs. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: Have you tried the default class which is generated by EclipseFX?

Comment: I'm not using EclipseFX, I'm afraid.

Comment: I think it's called e(fx)clipse

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118279/discussion-between-ifly6-and-adam-law).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
It works fine on Windows, but not on macOS.

The cause is that the current thread's class loader is null. This issue was resolved by configuring the class loader before loading FXML.

```java
if(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader() == null) {
    Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader());
}
fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("DialogFX.fxml"));
fxmlLoader.load();
```